# Python ssl module error: AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'enum_certificates'

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to use python to list the installed certificates installed in my machine. I'm using python 3.6.8. I'm using the code below. It works in Windows, but fails in CentOS:

```py
import ssl
from cryptography import x509

for store in ["CA", "ROOT", "MY"]:
    for cert, encoding, trust in ssl.enum_certificates(store):
        certificate = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(cert, backend=None)
        print(certificate.issuer, certificate.not_valid_after)
```

The CentOS error is:

```
AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'enum_certificates'
```

It is weird because the docs of ssl modules say that the `enum_certificates` method was [added in version 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.enum_certificates). It should be present.

How would I list the installed certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enum_certificates attribute in only available on Windows. In you link, just above where it says *`New in version 3.4.`* it says `Availability: Windows.`